# how to center a span vertical inside a button with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have a small rounded circle with a number inside inside a button. How can i center the span vertical inside the button?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary w-50 my-4">
    Comments Moderation <span class="approve-counter rounded-circle bg-danger text-white text-center float-right">5</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.approve-counter {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

As you can see, the red circle is not exactly vertical in the middle of the blue button

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vour83s9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **flex** and `align-items: center` to vertically center all items in the button. Apply the following styles to your button element:

```
.btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Or even better, you could simply use **Bootstrap 4 classes** in your `button` tag to achieve the same result:

```
<button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between btn btn-primary w-50 my-4">
    Comments Moderation <span class="approve-counter rounded-circle bg-danger text-white text-center float-right">5</span>
</button>
```